# SQL Server : VAR Value to Column Name

Tags: sql-server

I am moving over old system into a new one and there is some really stupid stuff going on but anyway I need to do this;

```
UPDATE tblSomething 
SET Column3 = 'Something' 
WHERE ID = 58
```

By using something like this;

```
DECLARE @No INT = 3

UPDATE tblSomething 
SET Column+@No = 'Something 
WHERE ID = 58
```

So I am trying to use a value as a column name. Please help...

Comment: Your problem is caused by a lack of proper normalization. So why not fix the underlying problem? Which will allow the use of "normal" tsql statements that are easier to write, debug, and understand. Dream a little.

Comment: Yes I am aware the the current system structure is not set-up correct from day one, that is why I am migrated to proper normalization. But first thing I need to do is move the data over from stupid column58 to actual real rows in TSQL and in a nice new table, which is what I am doing. That's why I asked about the the column name with value. The person below has answered correctly and now I have the data migrated. Thanks for the criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use variables as object names directly, you will have to use Dynamic SQL for this.

```
DECLARE @No INT = 3
DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    UPDATE 
        tblSomething 
    SET 
        Column' + + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @No) + ' = ''Something'' WHERE ID = 58'


PRINT (@DynamicSQL)

EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
```

Beware of inserting unsafe values on your dynamic sql (SQL Injection). It's not much problem with integers, but for databases, tables or columns you should use `QUOTENAME()` and limit the `VARCHAR` length to a decent value.

Comment: Clarify: "decent value" = to 128 characters or less, since if the input is greater than 128 characters then QUOTENAME returns NULL.